# Custom Link using branch.io

Tags: branch.io

Is it possible to create custom link with branch.io for example https://example.app.link/fzmLEhobLD so can I control **fzmLEhobLD** this parameter with my custom 10 digit parameter like amitpp8888. 
We basically want this because we provide each customer with unique refer url and we want to keep it as simple as possible.
They can remember their referral code which is combination of their first name and DOB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create Branch links with custom aliases.

**1. For Branch quick links (created on the Branch dashboard):**

You can add the custom alias, in the `Configure Options` tab

[image]

**2. When creating links via the SDK:**

You can specify the custom alias in the link properties

For e.g. in Android:

```
LinkProperties lp = new LinkProperties()
    .setChannel("facebook")
    .setFeature("sharing")
    .setCampaign("content 123 launch")
    .setStage("new user")
    .setAlias("hello");
```

**2. When creating links via the HTTP API:**

You can specify the custom alias in the link parameters

```
curl -XPOST https://api.branch.io/v1/url \
  -d '{
  "branch_key": "key_live_xxxxxxxxxx",
  "channel": "facebook",
  "feature": "onboarding",
  "campaign": "new product",
  "stage": "new user",
  "tags": ["one", "two", "three"],
  "alias": "hello",
  "data": {
    "$canonical_identifier": "content/123",
    "custom_boolean": true,
    "custom_integer": 1243,
    "custom_string": "everything",
    "custom_array": [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    "custom_object": { "random": "dictionary" }
  }
}'
```

PS: If you try to create a link with an alias which already exists and different link parameters than the previous link, the link will not be generated and you will receive an exception.

Comment: So we can share alias with users for example https://example.com/amit44; and that will act as deep link and open the correct app or webpage in browser?

Comment: If you have deeplinking correctly configured, it will work just as any other Branch link.

Comment: Can we set Alias with bulk create?

Comment: You cannot create alias links using the `v1/url/bulk` API endpoint. Maybe you can run a for loop using the `v1/url` endpoint to create alias links in bulk.

Comment: Quick Links can we add JSON object on the deep link using the dashboard

Comment: @AmrutaDeshmukh is there a way we can add different custom data to the same quick link through *query params*? If I have a link `xxx.app.link/alias?code=a1` branch sdk treats the link as a `+non_branch_link` (with `+clicked_branch_link: false`). Is there a way to get around this? I would not want to create a new link every time I want to invite a user to the app.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure with enterprise accounts, but with the basic package use will need to make a repository with the desired name `fzmLEhobLD`, then you link will be
`https://<github_username>.github.io/<fzmLEhobLD>/`.

l would advise making a github page for it as well.